# Regroup multiple spiders in a main spider

Tags: scrapy

I'm actually working on a project of scrapping using scrapy and I ended up with **37 spiders**. I want to do a cron-job for these spiders but first I want to regroup all of my 37 spiders in a **main spider**. And by doing it I'm going to do a single cron-job on the main spider instead of 37 cron-jobs.
Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a script that runs all these spider and use cron to schedule that?

See the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) for creating a script.

Here is an example snippet from one of my projects:

```
def run_spider_crawler(self):
    # .. other code here..

    runner = CrawlerRunner()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def crawl():
        yield runner.crawl(spider1)
        yield runner.crawl(spider2)
        yield runner.crawl(spider3)
        yield runner.crawl(spider4)
        yield runner.crawl(spider5)
        reactor.stop()

    crawl()
    reactor.run()  # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
```

Comment: I'm using user_agents + proxies. I don't know if it's the same thing for you, but I'm facing this problem now "proxy-pool is already defined as a collector" I searched on the net but I didn't find any solutions. I do understand that with my code or yours, we run sequentially and that's what causing the error of proxy pool

Comment: Here is my code :
```configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

for spider_name in runner.spiders.list():
    runner.crawl(spider_name)

d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()   ```